# S3: Getting Access Denied for user with AmazonS3FullAccess permission policy

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created an IAM user and applied a role that has granted the AmazonS3FullAccess and the AdministratorAccess, but when I try to upload a file to the budget I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message
<RequestId>58ADCB (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>78ADCBDFA4A2F2F1</RequestId>
<HostId>+nMvJhGbk4zKU//uYIMAjNJdjVLIPuQuARwq5c1Dsbd8anrqOCKwsUe/XDVRS3xE5rHVFgrBfsE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

There is the generated policy of the AmazonS3FullAccess permission:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Is clear for me that the policy above grants me access to ALL my budgets, but it seems that somehow this is forgotten.